# Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED filter invoked selectively

Tags: android, sms, telephony

I need to read text from incoming SMS and, as from title, I'm facing a strange behaviour: filter is correctly invoked when testing in android emulator and, on real phone, when using an SMS web service but not if SMS comes from another phone; below my code.

MANIFEST

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Of course permission is granted for all of them.

BROADCAST RECEIVER

```
public class SmsNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "[SmsNotificationReceiver]";

    public SmsNotificationReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) { return; }

        Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + action);
    }
}
```

RECEIVER REGISTRATION

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new SmsNotificationReceiver();
registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
```

Anything wrong I'm doing here? Does anyone met similar behaviour and solved it? If so please kindly address me to recognize what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the missed messages are actually SMS? Can you see them if you query the SMS Provider afterward; e.g., `getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, ...)`? Modern messaging clients will seamlessly integrate all messages types together; SMS, MMS, RCS, whatever. They can also silently switch between protocols for various reasons, like for a particular contact, etc. Whichever client(s) you're using might have something in settings about RCS, or Advanced Messaging, or Chat capability, or something like that, which you can disable to force regular SMS.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for helping and sorry for late reply. I tried querying for SMS and messages are not visible same for MMS so they should be RCS, which seems to be a kind of headache; any suggestion about documentation for listening incoming RCS? P.S. - In my test both sending and receiving phones are samsung and default messaging app have been used, further so far I cannot find any setting forcing regular SMS (although I'd prefer to avoid push users for "strange" settings), in both cases chat is disabled. Thanks.